# C: removing linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list

I've got a linked list of the following structures:

```
struct pomiar {
    unsigned int nr_pomiaru;
    unsigned int nr_czujnika;
    char data_i_czas[20];
    double temp;
    struct pomiar *nast;
};
```

I'm allocating all elements with `malloc()`: each element is pointed at by the previous one.

> While freeing the list, should I go through the whole list and free
>   the `*nast` pointers till the last one or what exactly should I do?

Comment: How is your linked list implemented? That's somewhat relevant?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I edited my question, hope it answers what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, you should go through the list, taking a copy of the `nast` pointer for the current element, then freeing the current element, then making the copied `nast` value into the current element.  You can't access the memory (reliably) after it is free — don't!  Hence the copying.  `void free_list(struct pomiar *list) { while (list != NULL) { struct pomiar *nast = list->nast; free(list); list = nast; } }`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you, that answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should go through the list, taking a copy of the `nast` pointer for the current element, then freeing the current element, then making the copied `nast` value into the current element. You can't access the memory (reliably) after it is free — don't! Hence the copying.

```
void free_list(struct pomiar *list)
{
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        struct pomiar *nast = list->nast;
        free(list);
        list = nast;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method, just like the ones from other answers work only for freeing one list. I've got five of them, not connected in any way. When I try to free one list (any of them), it works. When I want to free first one and then second one, it works only for the first one and second one produces an error "valid heap pointer". When I want to free second one and then the first one - second one is freed, but the first one produces mentioned error. Why could that be?

Comment: "CrtIsValidHeapPointer (pUserData)" to be exact.

Comment: We'd need to see how you're creating the other lists, but there isn't an obvious way for separate lists to share the data.  You could have one list as a suffix of another; if you didn't take extreme care, you'd end up freeing already freed memory.  But that's a tad improbable.

Comment: I think that the `"CrtIsValidHeapPointer (pUserData)"` means you're running on MS Windows and using the C RunTime (CRT) and `CrtIsValidHeapPointer` checks whether a heap pointer is valid and fires an assertion or something similar if the pointer is not valid.  At least, it is something along those lines.  As I said, we'd need to see the code that's creating the lists (or, at least, a 2-list MCVE — [MCVE] — version of the code).  If the lists are independent, there shouldn't be a problem.  If they're connected somehow, there could (would) be problems.  But it is hard to guess what you've got.

Comment: Okay wow, I have no idea what the first part of you comment mean. I will try to go through the code and draw everything to see what really is happening. Other parts of the program work just like they should though, which I think would be nearly impossible, if the lists were connected somehow.

Comment: You were right, there's been a huge mess in the lists, but I managed to clean it up I think and now it seems to work just fine, thank you a lot for the time you gave me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to free all the allocated memory for nodes of the list.

If to support that the list is declared something like

```
struct pomiar *head = NULL;
```

Then the function can look for example the following way.

```
void free_list( struct pomiar **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct pomiar *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->nast;
        free( tmp );
    }
}
```

and called like

```
free_list( &head );
```

In this case the original `head` will be equal to `NULL` after exiting the function and can be used anew as an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In order to free the list, you must go through the entire list and free each node explicitly.

```
void list_free(struct pomiar *head)
{
    struct pomiar *tmp = head;
    while(head)
    {
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = head;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The linked list is a data structure that is **unlike array** group of **non-contiguous memory locations**. This is the reason you have to traverse the entire linked list. Had it been an array, you would just need a pointer to the first element, and call free on it and that's it, because in arrays **it's contiguous memory locations.**